# Adding some numbers in Shell Script?

Tags: shell

How can I get the sum of the following number? They are getting multiplied before getting added.

```
Input File (count.txt)
2*4
2*1
3*1
3*1
2*1
2*1

Command I am using:
( echo 0 ; sed 's/$/ +/' count.txt; echo p ) | dc.
```

The Sum I am getting is 343 which is not correct. I am expecting 20 as sum.

```
2*4
2*1
3*1
3*1
2*1
2*1
```

Sum: 20 (Multiplication and then sum for each line)

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also do the job:

```
awk -F'*' '{i+=$1*$2} END{print i}' count.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
cat count.txt | tr \\n \+ | sed 's/$/\n/' | bc
```

be sure that there's no new line at the end of file, otherwise you must modify the sed expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat count | while read line; do echo $(($line)); done | awk '{i+=$1} END {print i}'
```

This is the best solution I could come up with, hope it helps.